# How to sum two elements of the array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sum, element

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"22,343", @"44,323",@"34,5678",@"22,725", nil];
```

i have  this array and I want to sum two values this array.
like this `array[0] + array [1]`

how to sum this elements? 
thanks !!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes i tried to   double mydouble1 = array[0];
                      double mudouble2 = array[1];       but this method is incorrect

Comment: `array[anIndex]` is a `NSString` object from your sample code, not a `int`, `NSInteger`, or other primitive. So `NSInteger sum = [array[0] integerValue] +  [array[1] integerValue];`

Comment: NSInteger sum = [array[0] integerValue] + [array[1] integerValue]      this code can not be faulted but sum = 66.   I want to sum = 66,666

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: your solution is not effective because  how to I place "," ?

Comment: Check my answer brother.I updated.Now it works.

Comment: your solution does not give the correct results. Because if you sum "44,323" and "34,5678"  your code return the 390,001 but this wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is

```
NSString *strVaue1 = [array[0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
NSString *strVaue2 = [array[1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
NSUInteger  arrValue1 = [strVaue1 integerValue];
NSUInteger  arrValue2 = [strVaue2 integerValue];
NSUInteger  sum = arrValue1 + arrValue2;
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // to get commas (or locale equivalent)
[fmt setMaximumFractionDigits:0]; // to avoid any decimal
NSString *result = [fmt stringFromNumber:@(sum)];
NSLog(@"The result is - %@",result);
```

The printed result is

```
The result is - 66,666
```